# Aligning QTabBar from stylesheets

Tags: macos, qt

I am trying to align position of tabs in QTabBar to the left. 
Does any one has any idea?

I was able to do this when I was using QTabWidget using style-sheet. Now, I have restriction that I cannot use QTabWidget. So have to do this in tab-bar.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "align positions of tabs"?  Do you want the tabs in a certain order, or do you want all the tabs pushed to the left, or do you want the text in the tabs left-aligned?  Also, what is it doing now?

Comment: want all the tabs pushed to the left. Tab by default are centrally align in tab bar.

Comment: you must mean the text of the tabs, not the tabs themselves?

Comment: I mean, I want to allign tabs themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From line 389 of my Qt 4.6.3 source:

```
Qt::Alignment tabAlignment = Qt::Alignment(q->style()->styleHint(QStyle::SH_TabBar_Alignment, 0, q));
```

This is the only place the alignment is set here and using QTabBar in the stylesheet does not work properly. I'd suggest then that it's only possible to do this by creating your own QStyle (this can be quite simple, just subclass an existing one) or by customising your local version of Qt.

Alternatively, if you have to use stylesheets, post a follow up question and link it here about the issues you've had with QTabWidget. They will probably be easier to fix.